# Problems copying file to home directory PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying copy a single file from the Plugin directory inside of my Wordpress installation to the root directory of the Wordpress installation.  I need the functionality to do this no matter where the installation is located.  It's for my Wordpress plugin, and it doesn't seem to be working on a site I tested.

Somehow I'm thinking that I'm not capturing each possible directory location in my `function destpath()` function.  I need it to successfully find the exact directories of the Plugin folder so that it copies the file (process.php) to the exact root directory, no matter the location of the Wordpress install.

```
function destpath() 
{ 
    $base = dirname(__FILE__); 
    $path = false; 

    if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname($base))."/wp-config.php")) { 
        $path = dirname(dirname($base))."/process.php"; 
    } else 
        if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/wp-config.php")) { 
            $path = dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/process.php"; 
        } else 
            $path = false; 

    if ($path != false) { 
        $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path); 
    } 
    return $path; 
} 

function pluginpath() 
{ 
    $base = dirname(__FILE__); 
    $path = false; 

    if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname($base))."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) { 
        $path = dirname(dirname($base))."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
    } else 
        if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) { 
            $path = dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
        } else 
            $path = false; 

    if ($path != false) { 
        $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path); 
    } 
    return $path; 
} 

copy(pluginpath(), destpath());
```

Comment: Did you check permissions for your folders?

Comment: Check your log files, for possible permission errors

Comment: I changed permissions on all sub-directories from top of Wordpress installation.  Still no change.  Thanks for the good suggestion.

Comment: Dan, I checked and it's telling me there's a parse error on line 117 and 118 (which is the first "if" statement in the code above), although the file is working and not causing my site to crash. What could possibly be the problem?  Wouldn't my site crash if there was truly a parse error?

Comment: Here's the path to the entire PHP file found in the Wordpress trunk directory.  http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/malware-finder/trunk/mwfinder.php

Comment: I believe I have found the problem.  The "malware finder" directory had a space between the words "malware" and "finder".  I'm guessing this caused a minor error, although the file didn't crash.  The error log showed the path as looking like "malware-finder".

Comment: Too many '@' suppressing errors .. Learn to catch all errors .. it makes debugging and maintenance easy

Comment: Can you remove the @ sign and paste the exact PHP error your script is outputting ??

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in mwfinder.php on line 117
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in mwfinder.php on line 118
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in mwfinder.php on line 118
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in mwfinder.php on line 118

Comment: Here's the path to the entire PHP file found in the Wordpress trunk directory. plugins.svn.wordpress.org/malware-finder/trunk/mwfinder.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/malware-finder/trunk/mwfinder.php), it looks like the `destpath` and `pluginpath` methods of the `MalwareFinder` class are being injected into the `printAdminPage` function:

Source code line:83:

```
function printAdminPage() {
```

Source code line:108 (appears to close if):

```
<?php }
```

Source code line:111-133 (still within printAdminPage):

```
function destpath() { ... }
```

Source code line:136-158 (still within printAdminPage):

```
function pluginpath() { ... }
```

Source code line:205:

```
}//End function printAdminPage()
```

Also, on lines 62 and 65, these php tags appear unnecessary.